# Using LWIP SNMP, errors occur when the second snmp_vabind_alloc is called

Tags: embedded, snmp, lwip

I'm trying to send a proper trap using the Light Weight Internet Protocol (LWIP) SNMP.

The SNMP Wiki states, a proper trap should have

> 1. a current sysUpTime value binding
> 2. an OID identifying the type of trap binding
> 3. an optional variable binding

However it errs with `vb->value != NULL` when the second `snmp_varbind_alloc` is called.

When only the variable binding is sent, and none other, the trap is sent to the Network Management Station ok.

Comment: Suggest you add a  SSCCE. See http://sscce.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is defined in RAM and the fields populated, effectively doing the allocate manually, then I can get two bindings to go out. It will single step but not run. So, now I need to look at making sure the RAM structures exists when it is being sent out, before I destroy them. So, I can add a delay, which is not ideal, or find a function which will tell me when the trap has been sent, so I can move on. I'm hesitant in posting code which doesnt work. When (if) I get it working, then I will show the code.

Comment: In opt.h increasing the value of  #define MEMP_NUM_SNMP_VALUE             from 3 to 9 allows the allocation of 2 more bindings. However, I found out that one binding is enough for a level 1 trap. Level 2 traps require the 3 bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for 3 bindings with opt.h changed from:

#define MEMP_NUM_SNMP_VALUE             3

to:

#define MEMP_NUM_SNMP_VALUE             9

```
struct snmp_obj_id sysupid = {9,{1,3,6,1,2,1,1,3,0}};
struct snmp_obj_id trapoid = {11,{1,3,6,1,6,3,1,1,4,1,0}};
struct snmp_obj_id pttnotifyoid = {8,{1,3,6,1,4,SNMP_ENTERPRISE_ID,3,18}};
static unsigned char trapOID[10] = { 0x2b, 6, 1, 4, 1, 0x82, 0xe4, 0x3d, 3, 18};
struct snmp_varbind *vb1, *vb2, *vb3;
u32_t *u32ptr, sysuptime;
void vSendTrapTaskDemo( void ){
   snmp_varbind_list_free(&trap_msg.outvb);
   vb1 = snmp_varbind_alloc(&sysupid,SNMP_ASN1_TIMETICKS, 4);
   snmp_get_sysuptime(&sysuptime);
   vb1->value_len=4;
   vb1->value_type=0x43;  //Timerticks
   u32ptr=vb1->value;
   *u32ptr=sysuptime;
   snmp_varbind_tail_add(&trap_msg.outvb,vb1);

   vb2 = snmp_varbind_alloc(&trapoid,SNMP_ASN1_OBJ_ID, 11);
   memcpy (vb2->value, trapOID, 10);
   snmp_varbind_tail_add(&trap_msg.outvb,vb2);

   vb3 = snmp_varbind_alloc(&pttnotifyoid, SNMP_ASN1_COUNTER, 4);
   vb3->value_len=4;
   vb3->value_type=0x02; //Integer32
   u32ptr=vb3->value;
   *u32ptr=1;
   snmp_varbind_tail_add(&trap_msg.outvb,vb3);

   snmp_send_trap(SNMP_GENTRAP_ENTERPRISESPC, &sysupid,18);
   snmp_varbind_list_free(&trap_msg.outvb);
}
```

The second binding has issues. 
The value of the OID is 0 (itu-t) when it should be:
1.3.6.1.4.1.45629.3.18

However, since level 1 needs only one binding, I'm going to forget the 3 binding method for now, until told that level 2 is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been posted a while ago, but I had the same issue as you, and couldn't find an answer...
I'm using LWIP on a STM32F107, and was completely unable to add a second varbind to my traps...

The solution was to increase the HEAP size of my µcontroller.
When using STM32CubeMX, it's located (for me) line 61 of the startup_stm32f107xc.s file, and has a default value of 0x200 (512 Bytes), I simply doubled that to be 0x400.

```
; <h> Heap Configuration
;   <o>  Heap Size (in Bytes) <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
; </h>

Heap_Size      EQU     0x400
```

I hope this will help whoever is trying to use LWIP!